# TableView cells repeating images during interaction even I am writing cell.imageview.image = nil at the beginning

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a custom tableviewCell ,
and when I am writing there below code

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "attendanceLogCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! AttendanceLogTableViewCell
cell.imageView.image = "someimag from cloud"
```

so when cells are loading the images inside the cells are repeating, 
so what to do now so that cells in the tableview doesn't repeat the images

Comment: if you need to show unique images in cells, you should pass unique images for each cell. What i see is you are passing just one image.. Where is the dataSource?

Comment: Show us data source (source of images), it looks like you assign the same image every time and thats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you are assigning the same image for every cell.
You should have dataSource where you hold your images and then assign from it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "attendanceLogCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? AttendanceLogTableViewCell {
        cell.imageView.image = imagesFromCloud[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    assertionFailure()
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```